# Linq To Sql Filtering Products by Tags

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I've got the following code:

```
var tagarray = tags.Split(',');
var products = new List<Product>();
foreach(var tag in tagarray)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
    {
        products.AddRange(entities.Products.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains(tag)).ToList());
    }
}
```

which does the job - but will add duplicate products if they match more than one tag. How could i rewrite the linq query to exclude products that are already in the list. I tried adding this to the mix:

```
private bool DoesProductAlreadyExist(List<Product> products, int id)
{
     return products.Exists(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

but I get an exception essentially saying the LINQ expression does not recognize the method. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but have you tried using `Distinct()`?

Similar to:

```
products.AddRange(entities.Products.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains(tag)).Distinct().ToList());
```

Play around with it.